# AWS CLI Commands

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

I want to get list of all files in S3 bucket with particular naming pattern.
For Eg if i have files like

```
aaaa2018-05-01
aaaa2018-05-23
aaaa2018-06-30
aaaa2018-06-21
```

I need to get list of all files for 5th month.Output should look like:

```
aaaa2018-05-01
aaaa2018-05-23
```

I executed the following command and the result was empty:

```
aws s3api list-objects --bucket bucketname --query "Contents[?contains(Key, 'aaaa2018-05-*')]" > s3list05.txt
```

when i check the s3list05.txt its empty. Also i tried the below command and

```
aws s3 ls s3:bucketname --recursive | grep aaaa2018-05* > s3list05.txt
```

this command lists me all the  objects present in the file.
Kindly let me know the exact command to get desired output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there. Try this:

```
aws s3 ls s3://bucketname --recursive | grep aaaa2018-05
```

or

```
aws s3 ls bucketname --recursive | grep aaaa2018-05
```

Comment: this option did work for me.I didnt try the first one as this one worked for me.Thanks a lot for the response

Answer (score 1):

The `Contains` parameter doesn't need a wildcard:

```
aws s3api list-objects --bucket bucketname --query "Contents[?contains(Key, 'aaaa2018-05')].[Key]" --output text
```

This provides a list of Keys.

`--output text` removes the JSON formatting.

Using `[Key]` instead of just `Key` puts them all on one line.

Comment: Thanks for the response i did try this option and this also worked for me as i wanted.Thank you